# Зачем всегда писать интерфейсы для репозиториев, сервисов и контроллеров в mvc?

Tags: java, mvc

Интерфейсы, как я понял, служат для абстракции. Один интерфейс - множество реализаций. Зачем тогда всегда писать интерфейсы в частности для репозиториев, для сервисного слоя, для контроллеров? В 99% случаев реализация интерфейса будет только одна. Единственное что приходит на ум, это ограничение доступа к методам реализации с помощью интерфейса для использования в других классах. Что можно почитать по этой теме?

Comment: Интерфейс может и не предполагать, что в вашем проекте будет множество реализаций. Даже если она одна, то в любой момент вы можете сменить одну реализацию на другую. С помощью интерфейса нельзя ограничить доступа к методам. Зато можно показать какие из методов нужны в для использования в другом классе, если мы говорим про принцип I из SOLID

Comment: "можно показать какие из методов нужны в для использования в другом классе" - это я и имел ввиду под ограничением доступа.